# Heroku dash app error - traceback FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I'm trying to deploy my first dash application to Heroku, but no matter what I try, I keep getting a **H10 app crashed error**. When inspecting the heroku logs, I see that there is a FileNotFoundError (I suspect this is what is causing the crash). I followed a tutorial online which laid out how to reference other files in the folder:

```
PATH = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
DATA_PATH = PATH.joinpath("../datasets").resolve()
top_games = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH.joinpath("topgames.csv"))
```

[image: Folder structure, code and error logs snip]

The only error I can see in the logs is *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/datasets/topgames.csv'*. Can anybody think of a reason as to why the app isn't recognising the *topgames* dataset with this code - or is it likely another error causing the crash?

P.S my app successfully deploys to Heroku, I just get an application error and nothing is shown. When I run the app on my localhost using the same file structure, it works successfully also.

My github has the full code: https://github.com/Kasheme/Chess-Games-Analysis

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved. For anyone who comes across this kind of error in the future, if your app reads from a dataset which is a text/csv file, make sure that you read your data from the raw GitHub file:

```
games_dataframe = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kasheme/Chess-Games-Analysis/master/datasets/games.csv")
```

Some tutorials I saw online say you should import pathlib and read the data that way. This will work when you deploy it to your local server but not when you try to deploy it to Heroku.